# Getting date from google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm developing a game for android. I use the google play services for the multiplayer functionality.

I want to integrate an ingame currency, which is reset to a fixed amount every day. Every game round the user plays will cost him 1 coin of this currency. Additionally i want to integrate in-app purchases to buy packages of coins, which are indepentant from that daily amount of coins.

My question concerns the date request when starting the app, which decides wether the user gets coins for that day, or if he already got them. If i just fetch the local date, the user could just change the phones date and get the coins even if he already got them for this day. So my question is, whats the best way to get the current date? I already use the google play services, so is there a way to fetch the date from there ? Otherwise, that needs the user to be connected to the internet. Any suggestion on this ?

Another question is, where to save the coins. Locally would be the easiest option. But is it safer to use the google play services cloud stuff for this too ? That would have the advantage to work cross device.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't trust the user's device you may want to get time from an external server that you control.

For storing the coins remotely, please check out the [Google Play Saved Games Service](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames).  You can store arbitrary data there and use it to sync coins and other information across a user's devices.

Comment: I'm a little concerned the saved games service lets the user handle his saved games. So, if i save the date the user got his last coins there, and the user has the option of deleting his saved games, he could just do that and receive coins for the current day over and over. Are u sure the Google Play Saved Games Service gives me, the developer control oder the data, and not the user over some Google Play Games Console ? See also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464096/save-data-to-cloud-in-android-game)

Comment: The Google Play Saved Games Service Description says: "All Saved Games are stored in your players' Google Drive Application Data Folder. This folder can only be read and written by your game - it cannot be viewed or modified by other developers’ games, so there is additional protection against data corruption. In addition, Saved Games are insulated from direct tampering by players so they cannot modify individual Saved Games."    Sounds like the player has indeed no control over the saved games data. But the "individual" sounds like he is able to clear all his saved games if he likes...

Comment: Just found [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3129939?hl=en). So its possible for the user to clear the data, and thus he can reset the coins manually, which i want to avoid.